# IIS Redirections whit query string

Tags: iis, redirect

I have a url:

http://example.com/post.aspx?post=postname

I want redirect it on IIS to :

http://example.com/postname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Download [UrlRewrite Module 2.0](http://www.iis.net/downloads/URLRewrite) From Microsoft
2. Install on server.
3.Put Code inner  (system.webServer) Section on Web.Config file. 
 
4.Save.
5.Enjoy Now.

```
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="PostRedirect1">
                <match url="^Post/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="post.aspx?post={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
       </rewrite>
```